# Why can't I call setProps() on a component returning a list of divs in enzymejs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have an issue understanding how `setProps` is meant to work in enzymejs library.

To start with an example:

```
const CompA = (props) => {
    return props.listOfNumbers.map((number) => <div>{number}</div>);
};

it("Test CompA", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<CompA listOfNumbers={[1]}/>);  // -> (Debug log) ShallowWrapper {length: 1}
    wrapper.setProps({listOfNumbers: [1, 2]});              // -> (Debug log) ShallowWrapper {length: 2}
    wrapper.setProps({listOfNumbers: [1, 2, 3]}); // Enzyme error:  Method “rerender” is meant to be run on 1 node. 2 found instead.
});
```

From enzymejs docs.

`setProps: A method that sets the props of the root component, and re-renders.`

So, I assume the root component is checked within the `ShallowWrapper` returned from `shallow` function.
And, if I understand the above enzyme error correctly, it is complaining that I am trying to call `setProps` on a wrapper which has a list of nodes, not a node.

But, my confusion is, shouldn't I be able to call `setProps` on `CompA` and test the output of it's render function, whatever that output is?

My impression here is, I can call `setProps` only if the component under test returns one node from it's render function. And that **one node** is the **root component** mentioned in enzyme doc.

Comment: You should wrap the returned array within `<React.Fragment>`.

Comment: Solved the issue. Thanks @AdrianoRepetti. But still, this is confusing to me. `setProps` is meant to set the props of the component under test, `CompA` in this case. But, it's dependent on what type of data `CompA` renders. For `setProps`, needs to be one node, I still have a feeling this is wrongly done.

Comment: You're right, from React 16 you can return an array but (at least in my experience) Enzyme really didn't keep up.